# how to sort an NSMutableArray having MutableDictionary in it?

Tags: objective-c

i have a NSMutableArray "arrayCompaniesData" passing an NSMutableDictionary in it like   [arrayCompaniesData addObject:mutableDic], in mutableDic i have Keys emp_id, name and description i want to sort this mutableArray by key 'name' how i can do this???? i did use NSSortDescriptor but that don't work.......

```
 NSArray *convertedArray_1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayCompaniesData];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    NSArray *srt = [convertedArray_1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortArray];
```

Comment: Why is your key: @"key" ? That isn't what you want to search by... Change it to @"name"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably blocks

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDictionary *first = (NSDictionary*)a;
    NSDictionary *second = (NSDictionary*)b;
    return [first[@"name"] compare:second[@"name"]];
}];
```